# Best way to inherit both a group of annotations and a group of methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I want to have a particular annotation in multiple classes. I know I could do this in spring by defining a new annotation with:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@annotation1
@annotation2
@...
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation{}
```

And then annotating my classes with @MyCustomAnnotation

I also want those classes to have some particular methods, which I could do with simple inheritance.

Now, since I want both things for the same classes, I was wondering if I could do both things at once, as in defining a class with the methods to inherit from, that also has the annotations, so the annotations would be inherited with it.

I've been playing with @Inherited with no luck. Even tried using something like

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@annotation1
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation{}

@MyCustomAnnotation
public class X {... methods here ...}

public class Y extends X { ... }
```

which would force me to have one @interface for my annotations and one class for my methods, but somehow this hasn't worked either (Y didn't get annotated with annotation1)

What am I doing wrong? What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Y didn't get annotated with annotation1'? The @Inherited only means that Y is considered having the annotation and you should be able to verify that using reflection.

Comment: @DennisV I mean the functionallity of annotation1 wasn't there for Y doing this. Isn't this the expected behaviour?